# Can I thread hang in ::poll

Tags: multithreading, sockets

We are seeing a big amount of ptypes posix threads hanging in socket poll even though the call is made with a timeout of 200 ms. Any ideas what can lead to such a situation?

Comment: Err, nothing is happening to the FDs being polled?

Comment: @IadaManiak any update on this?